# Is the time step related to sampling frequency in my program? MatLab

Tags: matlab, fft

If I code such as this:

```
for t=1:nt
  Z = Zwat + dQ*dt*idx2 - sigma*dt ;
end
```

Where `dt` is my time step and, for one of my runs, `nt=10,000`. I save the variable `Z` every 50 time steps.

Will my sampling frequency then be `50*(dt^-1)`, for the purposes of doing a FFT using the built in MatLab function?

Comment: This is a maths problem, not a programming problem.  But the answer is: it depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can You edit your question please and put all the code in it?

Comment: The rest of my code is not relevant to the question. Can you clarify Oli? Or can you give me a reference because I still do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you originally sample at dt, and then resample this data keeping 1 for every 50 pts, then your new sample time is 50*dt, and your new sample rate it 1/(50*dt), and these new values are what you'd use in Matlab (or anywhere else).  Was this your question?

Answer (score 1):

If your dt is say 0.01s and you were saving every 50th sample then you are sampling every 0.5s and your sampling frequency will be 1/(0.01*50) = 2 Hz